# Tableau left join w/o overlap (A-B)

Tags: tableau-api

How do I get a left join without the intersection part(A-B)? My Tableau version does not have a custom SQL query tab.

Comment: what version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to do a left join with condition null in the right table like SQL:
[image]

To do it in Tableau, you have to do left join in the union and add a Filter (Left, up corner) by the key column with nulls values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cristian! How can I export this join resultset on the data source sheet? I believe it is different from export to crosstab excel.

Comment: Hi, Jaish, Can you add as a new question? and then I will answer, add the link to the question here.